# PDF blob in eclipse birt

Tags: eclipse, pdf, blob, birt

I've a MySql DB with table documento: this entity has a blob column named doc. Into doc column I've saved a pdf doc. I would retrieve this doc into dynamic image of eclipse birt. I've tried to run this feature but I've a problem. Is possible this kind operations?

Answer (score 0):

> Is possible this kind operations?

No.
A PDF is just not an image.